# Differences in paths between gazebo and rosrun gazebo_ros gzserver

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I have my files in the following structure:

```
~/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin: mars.world
~/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/models: model database, model.sdf files in subfolders
~/gazebo_source/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros
```

My environment variables are set up as follows:

> GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/models:/home/yn/faster_dev/trunk/gazebo/models
> GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/home/yn/local/share/gazebo-1.9:/home/yn/local/share/gazebo_models:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/models
> GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
> GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/yn/local/lib/gazebo-1.9/plugins:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin/build:/home/yn/faster_dev/trunk/gazebo/plugin/build
> GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models

When I run "gazebo mars.world" from any location the world is loaded with all textures and models found, howvere 'rosrun gazebo_ros gzserver mars.world" can only find the world file if I run the command from folder containing the mars.world file, and in this case a number of resources (png for heightmap and textures) cannot be found.

Is there any difference in the paths or environment variables used by gazebo and gazebo_ros?

Yasho

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3934/differences-in-paths-between-gazebo-and-rosrun-gazebo_ros-gzserver/) by [ynevatia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/448/ynevatia/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ynevatia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/448/ynevatia/) on 2013-07-30**:
The problem lies with the scripts in *gazebo_ros/scripts*. These call the *setup.sh* from Gazebo, which was overwriting the environment variables I had set in my .bashrc with default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I finally figured out the problem: it lies with a conflict in the scripts in gazebo_ros/scripts and the way I setup the environment variables. the gazebo_ros scripts call the setup.sh from Gazebo, which was overwriting the environment variables I had set in my .bashrc with default values. without changing how I saw the environment variables outside the execution.

By commenting out the relevant lines in *gazebo_ros/scripts/gazebo* and building it again (for safety), *roslaunch gazebo_ros mars_world.launch* works.

---

Originally posted by [ynevatia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/448/ynevatia/) with karma: 41 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1